# Tableau: can I have a single filter reference multiple columns while allowing for multiple selection?

Tags: filter, tableau-api

So I have some data that looks like this:

| Person ID | Condition A | Condition B | Condition C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | No |
| 2 | No | Yes | Yes |
| 3 | No | No | Yes |
| 4 | Yes | No | No |

Ideally, I would like to have a single filter that lists all 3 conditions and allows the user to select which conditions they would like to require a person to have, but someone could have any of the conditions (not necessarily all of them). So if someone had all 3 boxes checked, they would find people who had any of those 3 conditions. If someone selected conditions A and B, they would keep people who had condition A **OR** condition B (but not necessarily both).

For example, if you selected Condition B, IDs 1 and 2 would be kept. If you selected conditions A and B, IDs 1,2, and 4 would be kept.

I do not want to pivot my data since my real data is far larger and more complicated than the example I've provided here. Curious if anyone is able to provide some help on whether this is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Create 3 parameters on the sheet for the user to check:  want-A,  want-B, want-C,  which are each boolean (default false,each displayed as single-value-list)
Create a calculated field "selector" with formula:

```
([cond-A] = "yes" AND [want-A]) OR
([cond-B] = "yes" AND [want-B]) OR
([cond-C] = "yes" AND [want-C])
```

then filter on selector = true

Currently visible in my Tableau Public as "triselector"
https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/wade.schuette/viz/triselector/Sheet1?publish=yes

Comment: So it looks like maybe you need to have each condition as its own filter (i.e. in your example you have 3 filters, one for each condition). That would definitely work, but I really would need it to be in a single filter. The data here is just an example and my real data has a lot more conditions than just 3 (and having everyone listed as an individual filter is probably not a great option). But thank you!

Comment: @RandyRobinson It isn't three filters. It is three user-defined calculations that are combined into a single filter. You can create user defined calculations as complex as you want and combine them into a single filter.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you have access to it, one way to do this that works for any number of Conditions is to pivot your Condition columns into rows using Tableau Prep Builder.

Otherwise I believe you can pivot columns in Excel.
Here's my raw data in Excel
[image: raw data]

Instructions for pivoting using Prep Builder:
https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-us/prep_pivot.htm

3 views:

[image: pivot table step 1]

[image: pivot flow step 2]

[image: pivoted output]

Then you'll end up with a single field like "Pivot1 Names" with values "ConditionA", "Condition B", Condition C", etc. which you can use for the user-visible filter with as many check boxes as there are conditions.

It produces a "hyper" file for input to Tableau and this won't work for Tableau Public.  ( Don't blame me!)

If you coded "yes" and "no" values in your original columns then you also need to make a computed field "HasCondition" with some formula like

if [Cond] = "yes" then TRUE ELSE FALSE END

Then put both Pivot1-Names and HasCondition into your filters card, selecting only TRUE for HasCondition.  Select all avleus for Pivot1-Names ( and then the user will
unselect most of them )

Then put ID or Name in Rows,  Pivot1Names in colums,  Condition as Text, select Table in Showme, and you end up with this:

[image: image of worksheet]